# PyXB module not recognised

Tags: pyxb

I have installed pyxb module regular way (python setup.py install) and here is the output:

```
Found bundle in pyxb/bundles/common
Found bundle in pyxb/bundles/dc
Found bundle in pyxb/bundles/wssplat
Found bundle in pyxb/bundles/saml20
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_scripts
running install_lib
running install_scripts
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/pyxbgen to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/pyxbwsdl to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/pyxbdump to 755
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyXB-1.2.4.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyXB-1.2.4.egg-info
```

However, I keep getting message:

```
ImportError: No module named pyxb
```

when running a script which contains:

```
import pyxb
import pyxb.binding
import pyxb.binding.saxer
import StringIO
import pyxb.utils.utility
import pyxb.utils.domutils
```

Does anyone have an idea why this may occur?

Comment: >>> sudo pip install pyxb

Comment: or >>> sudo apt-get install python-pyxb

Comment: or download the module and open interpreter python, and pass this line : >>> import sys;  sys.path.insert(0, "path_of_module")

Comment: 'sudo apt-get install python-pyxb' gave me: E: Unable to locate package python-pyxb

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it was a permission issue: when running the script as sudo it successfully imports pyxb. setup.py script installed pyxb as:
`drwxr-s--- 7 root staff 4096 May 19 16:30 pyxb`